# Testing actual video file can play

Tags: javascript, html5-video

JavaScript has the canPlayType method to test if the browser can play a video file. But for more accurate results it needs a string such as "video/mp4; codecs="avc1.66.13, mp4a.40.2". Is there any way for JavaScript to run a test directly on a video file to check it will play, or alternatively to retrieve more accurate codec information with JavaScript, or perhaps even PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something like that, it's called `canplaythrough`.

> The canplaythrough event is fired when the user agent can play the
>   media, and estimates that enough data has been loaded to play the
>   media up to its end without having to stop for further buffering of
>   content.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplaythrough

There's also an `error` event that fires when the video fails to load or can't be played by the browser

```
var v = document.createElement('video'),
    s = document.createElement('source');

v.appendChild(s);

s.src  = "simpsons.mp4";
s.type = "video/mp4";

s.addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
    // catch errors
}, false);
```

Comment: In my particular case I would like to provide a fallback if a video can't be played, I assume though that using canplaythrough will mean that no event will be fired?

Comment: @MattyBalaam - if you want to catch errors, a video has a `error` event that fires if something goes wrong, for instance that the browser can't play the file

Comment: Using the error event gets the behaviour I require. Many thanks.

Comment: On closer testing, unfortunately if there is a valid poster element, the error event will not fire. Any other ideas apart from removing the poster element and triggering a fallback with JavaScript?

Comment: You mean the `poster` attribute, the one that takes an image? I had no idea that had any effect on the validity of the video file, but if it does, you probably have to create a video element in javascript and test it there, something like the code above ?

Comment: It is on Firefox 35 beta at least on MAC OS X Yosemite. Cloning without the poster seems like the only way in this case.

Comment: Sounds strange, but if that's what works, I guess that's the way you'll have to do it.

Comment: I recommend using `loadedmetadata` or `canplay` instead of `canplaythrough`. They will/should fire faster. `canplaythrough` needs to wait for a lot more data to load before it fires.